# Geographical maps on Microsoft Visual Studio 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to insert a map of the United Kingdom into a report on Visual Studio 2012. It seems I need a ESRI shapefile (.shp) - anyone know where I can get one of these?

Answer (score 0):

This is something you could have googled, but perhaps [this](http://www.statsilk.com/files/country/StatPlanet_UK.zip) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Dave. I tried this already, but when I tried to open the map.shp file I got an error that said "No spatial data available", hence why I came here and posted the question.